Interpretation of Heisenberg Uncertainty Relation
If $A$ is an observable and $\psi$ the state of a quantum mechanical system, then the inner product $E_A(\psi)=(A\psi,\psi)$ is the mean of observed values of $A$ in state $\psi$.
Likewise $E_{A^2}(\psi)=(A^2\psi,\psi)$ is the mean of the squares of observed values of $A$
in state $\psi$ and so
$$
\Delta_A(\psi):=E_{A^2}(\psi)-E_A(\psi)^2
$$
is simply the variance of observed values of $A$ in state $\psi$.
The Heisenberg Uncertainty Relation then reads
$$
\Delta_A(\psi)\Delta_B(\psi)\geq |E_{[A,B]}(\psi)|^2/4,
$$
where $[A,B]=AB-BA$ is the commutator of $A$ and $B$. This is simply a statement about the variances of two random variables and has nothing to do with any simultaneous observations of $A$ and $B$.
Likewise in ordinary statistics an inequality of the form $Var(X)Var(Y)\geq\epsilon$ has nothing to do with any simultaneous observations of the random variables $X$ and $Y$.
However the usual interpretation of the Heisenberg Uncertainty Relation is stated as follows: if $A$ and $B$ do not commute, then, in general, it is not possible to simultaneously measure both $A$ and $B$ to arbitrary accuracy. Without further argument this claim seems to have literally nothing to do with the above inequality. So where does this interpretation come from?

because both variances refer to the same state function $\psi$

@hynortnex OK, thanks. Accepted as an answer if so stated.

The interpretation that the variances $\mathbf {Var}[\hat A]$ and $\mathbf {Var}[\hat B]$ of two observables refer to simultaneous measurement are due to that both quantities refer to the same state vector (wave function) $\psi$. Actual simultaneity of observations is not really needed, for one could, in principle, prepare several QM systems in the same initial states but at different times and measure the various observables at later times as long as the measurements are in the same time evolved states.

yes it is essential to understand that "simultaneous" does not refer to simultaneous in time.

this question may also be of interest https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146139/uncertainty-relation-for-non-simultaneous-observation

The idea is simply that if $\Delta_A(\psi) = 0$, then you can measure $A$ for $\psi$ definitely (because $\psi$ is an eigenstate of $A$). Such eigenstates with $\Delta_A(\psi) = 0$ are the outcomes of any (perfect, strong) measurement of $A$.
An inequality of the form $\Delta_A(\psi)\Delta_B(\psi) > 0$ for all $\psi$ then means there exists no state that could be the outcome of a simultaneous measurement of $A$ and $B$, i.e. there exists no $\psi$ that is both an eigenstate of $A$ and of $B$. This is stronger than the "if two operators don't commute, they have no common eigenbasis" you could derive from $[A,B] \neq 0$ alone, since the non-zero commutator does not forbid the existence of some common eigenstates, only of a common eigenbasis.
